# Android studio is unable to initialize ADB

Tags: android, adb

First I was having an issue of **Error running app** no default activity found, I somehow fixed that via reinstalling the android studio. my current android version is **3.3.2**, now I can not connect any device via USB, it is just showing initializing ADB for like 1 second and then vanishes without recognizing the deployment device. It might be a primitive issue or maybe bug, I don't know, but one thing is for sure, it is an immense irritative process that is why I'm here finally, anyone? I'll appreciate your effort.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem isn't in your USB cable.

Just open `Android Studio` terminal and type this

```
adb.exe start-server
```

Restart `AS` and it should work.

If that didn't work, maybe there is an `ADB` instance that is running, you should kill it with this command

```
Kill -9 adb
```

Comment: I'm using windows and it was showing API-MS-WIN-CRT-LOCALE-L1-1-0.DLL is missing, I downloaded and added it, but now it is showing The procedure entry point ucrtbase.create_locale could not be located in dll API-MS-WIN-CRT-LOCALE-L1-1-0.DLL.

Comment: I'm using windows command, in android terminal it read as * daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *

Comment: but no luck even after daemon start.

Comment: Do you have your device driver installed in your laptop, and do you enable developer mode in your mobile phone ?

Comment: Try enabling and disabling USB debugging in the device settings. Also try those two commands in the AS terminal : `adb kill-server` then `adb start-server`

Comment: Brother, I'm quite experienced in android development, I appreciate your suggestion, I did, whatever I could, I did nearly everything, btw, I have two paths for adb, 1st is located in C:/adb and seconds one is C:\Users\rahulsync\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools, why is that?

Comment: Sorry for my bad english, I'm in no mood to look for grammer, I need a fix asap for it.

Comment: Everything was working fine untill morning, yes I have adb interface and driver.

Comment: And delete the ADB.exe which is here `C:/adb`

Comment: I think it is a better suggestion somewhat, thank you for your time bro, I'll do it, and share response after.

Comment: Update: after deleting c:/adb, I can not start server, becuase it is showing no such command adb and even after updating sdk it doesn't find the device.

Comment: Now the last thing I going to do is to completely remove the android sdk and reinstall, hope that might change something.

Comment: You should add your plateform-tools to global variables

Comment: I strongly believe that's your problem

Comment: copy this `C:\Users\rahulsync\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools` and add it to you environment paths in system .

Comment: I mean the path of adb or platform-tools to environment variables?

Comment: Got it, but I have to install sdk tools and android studio from scratch :)

Comment: And why is that ? the path of  platform-tools because it has adb.exe inside